# i am getting a javascript alert undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am getting a javascript alert undefined. I want to alert my `item_id` when the input is given in quantity which is in the textbox. But when I give it, it gives an alert undefined.

```
var item_id=$("#item_"+i).val();alert(item_id);
```

is not showing alert in javascript. My model and controller is also not showing the item. Please help

My view:

```
<td style='width:20%' id='producttd_1'>
  <select name='item[]' id='item_1' class="form-control selectpicker"  style='width:100%'  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" >
    <?php
    if(!empty($prolist))
    {
    print_r($prolist);
        foreach($prolist as $pro)
        {
            $opn1.="<option value='".$pro['id']."'>".$pro['product_name']."</option>";


        }
    }
    ?>
  </select>
</td>
<td style='width:7%'><input type='text' name='nos[]' id='nos_1' class="form-control" style='width:100%'/></td>
<td style='width:7%'><input type='text' name='quantity[]' id='quantity_1' class="form-control addrow quantity"  style='width:100%' onKeyup='calc(1);'/></td>
<td style='width:7%'><input type='text' name='rate[]' id='rate_1' class="form-control addrow" style='width:100%' onKeyup='calc(1);'/></td>
```

My ajax

```
function calc(i)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        add_row();
    }
    else
    {
        var item_id=$("#item_"+i).val();
        alert(item_id);
        var rate=$("#rate_"+i).val();
        //alert(rate);
        if(item_id=="")
        {
            alert("Select a product");
            $("#item_"+i).focus();
        }

        else
        {
            var quantity=$("#quantity_"+i).val();
            $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>sales/product_det',
            data: ({"item_id":item_id,"quantity":quantity,"rate":rate }),
                    dataType: 'html', 
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) {
                        data=data.split("-");
                        $("#rate_"+i).val(data[0]);
                        $("#amount_"+i).val(data[1]);
                        $("#cgst_"+i).val(data[2]);
                        $("#sgst_"+i).val(data[3]);
                        $("#igst_"+i).val(data[4]);
                        calc_total();
                } 

            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
function product_det()
    {
        $item=$this->input->post('item_id');
        echo $item;
        $quantity=$this->input->post('quantity');
        echo $quantity;
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $amount="";
        $cgst="";
        $sgst="";
        $igst="";
        $stock="";
        $product_det=$this->sale_model->get_productDet($item);
        $stockdet=$this->sale_model->getstock($item);


        if(!empty($product_det))
        {

                if($rate=="" || $rate==0)
                {
                    $rate=$product_det['sale_rate'];
                }
                $amount=$rate*$quantity;
                $cgst=$product_det['CGST'];
                $sgst=$product_det['SGST'];
                $igst=0;

        }

        echo $rate."/".$amount."/".$cgst."/".$sgst."/".$igst."/".$stockdet."/";

    }
```

My model:

```
function get_productDet($item)
{
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('product');
     $this->db->where('id',$item);
     $res=$this->db->get()->row_array();
     return $res;
}
```

Comment: I guess if you don't selected anything at the beginning, the ajax will not recognize the val()

Comment: You created select options in $opn1 but you did not printed it. I'm sure that you are not getting any <option>tag inside select .

Comment: Note, that this will work only in browsers implementing global `Event` object, this won't work f.e. in FireFox.

Comment: var item_id=$("#item_"+i).val();
                alert(item_id); please check this line. 
use like this var itemid = "#item_"+i

Comment: I have already selected category and item..when i select quantity..my item_id alert is showing undefined..var quantity=$("#quantity_"+i).val();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>sales/product_det',
                    data: ({"item_id":item_id,"quantity":quantity,"rate":rate }),

Comment: @Vinod kumar G...when i use this ,it is not showing any value..

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected option value, not the select itself:

```
var item_id=$("#item_1").find(":selected").text();
alert( item_id );
```